# dmesg -n 7 doesn't print anything, but dmesg prints a lot

Tags: linux-kernel, dmesg

As stated:

```
$> dmesg
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacc
...

$> dmesg -n 2
[ root@jamin ] ~
$> dmesg -n 7
[ root@jamin ] ~
$> dmesg -n 8
dmesg: unknown level '8'
```

dmesg -n should print everything below n, right? But it doesn't print anything at all. Why?

Answer (score 0):

No -n actually *sets* the level for future messages that will be displayed to the console. So by doing -n 2 you just *set* that from that moment on you'll just see messages of level 2 and below on your console.

Comment: When I enter dmesg the next time you mean?

Comment: I can't see that it has any effect. Is it when the next message comes in to /dev/kmsg? By console, do you mean terminal? Or all terminals to come or what does it mean? stdout?